# estructura de un objeto en json

Tags: json, objeto

Buenas noches como puedo convertir este arreglo php a un objeto con estructura json

```
 $arreglo = array(
  ['pv'=>"MATEO BENITEZ 89 COL. centro TUXTEPEC MEXICO CP 38500", 'latitud'=>20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=> -100.65457702572893],
  ['pv'=>"JOSEFINA ENRIQUEZ 102   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC CP 68300", 'latitud'=>20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=> -100.65457702572893],
  ['pv'=>"AGUSTINA CARRERA 96   COL. CENTRO TUXTEPEC    CP 68300", 'latitud'=> 20.48871324385829, 'longitud'=>-100.65457702572893]);
```

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el la funcion `json_encode`. Esta devuelve un string con la
representación JSON de el valor que le des, o `false` en caso de que ocurra un
error.

```
$arreglo_json = json_encode($arreglo);
```

[Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)